# Resources to keep a track on open Ph.D. positions in specific sub-fields/topics of quantum computing

Tags: resource-request

I was wondering where to look for open Ph.D. positions for specific sub-fields/topics of quantum computing like error correction, optimization, quantum chemistry, etc. It is preferable if the offers/positions can be sorted subfield-wise or topic-wise.

Comment: What exactly are you looking for? Advertisements for PhD positions? Or a list of sub-fields of quantum computer (i.e. error correction, optimization, quantum chemistry)

Comment: More positions but categorized by sub-field but having a description of the main topic/subject/tasks one would work on. Or are PhD positions not really specific when offered?

Comment: I don't think stackexchange is a good place for these kind of career-advice questions

Comment: @gIS I am not asking for advice but resource request. That may also be useful to look for specific directions of research about QC. But if it is a problem, we can close the question.

Comment: http://qurope.eu/ has job advertisements in quantum science.

Comment: @Blue I don't see how academia.se would be a better fit, since it is about field-specific job ads.  Not sure it is a good fit for this site, but we could have one community wiki list about "Where can I find job ads in QIT."

Comment: @NorbertSchuch Umm, yes, you are probably right. I browsed through the Academia SE meta posts about their scope it does seem that there's a chance that this would get closed there as a "Shopping" question. In some cases, "big-list" questions like this have accepted on some sites, for example [this one](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/2279/universities-known-for-computational-physics).

Comment: @cnada I've edited the question to make it more clear, based on your comments above. Feel free to roll-back.

Comment: @Blue I think this would be exactly a question where the answer would be a community effort: A list of resources.  Or do you want one answer per resource?

Comment: @NorbertSchuch Okay, well, then we'd have to get a moderator to agree with us (if we want this to be community wiki). Anyway, one answer per resource would get too messy. Maybe different answers for different sub-fields like "quantum chemistry", "theoretical quantum computing" (as in theoretical computer science - complexity theory, algorithms and all that), "quantum optics", etc would be better?

Comment: @Blue I think the "sorted by field XYZ" makes it quite unsuitable as a question.  I think a general resource list, with some extra info about each list (focus etc.) would be more helpful.   Otherwise we end up having 20 questions with different types of lists.  This is also impossible to maintain.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch Okay, I think I agree with you. A general resource list (PhD offers) with some description for each resource should be good enough. People should be free to either answer with just a single resource or multiple resources - something like the book-recommendation threads on Physics SE. BTW do you mind adding that site "qurope" which you mentioned as an answer below (with 1-2 lines of description)? It will serve as a good example answer.

Comment: Thanks guys for your inputs. @Blue it is fine like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may keep a tab on the [Jobs page](https://www.quantiki.org/jobs) or in particular the [Ph.D. positions page](https://www.quantiki.org/jobs?field_job_type_tid%5B%5D=628) on [Quantiki](https://www.quantiki.org/). You can view the extended descriptions for each position by clicking on the individual position names and see the project details like location, duration of the Ph.D., potential supervisors, etc. The positions are not restricted to any specific country as such and cannot be sorted according to sub-fields (as far as I know).

Comment: Ok thanks. I was already aware of that one but indeed the fact that it is not possible to sort the result of a search (it will not be in chronological order) or filter is a bit bad.