# What are mailing lists that advertise conferences and academic positions in the area of quantum computing?

Tags: resource-request, research

I am aware of Oxford's Quantum Foundations mailing list that regularly advertises conferences and openings for academic positions related to quantum theory. What are other mailing lists that advertise stuff like this in the area of quantum computing?

For the interested: you can subscribe to the Quantum Foundations list by sending an email to `quantum-foundations-subscribe@maillist.ox.ac.uk`

Also, this question seems to be related: [Resources to keep a track on open Ph.D. positions in specific sub-fields/topics of quantum computing](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/4438/resources-to-keep-a-track-on-open-ph-d-positions-in-specific-sub-fields-topics)

Answer (score 4):

You have those two mailing lists in quantum computing:

1. [Quantum Computing Report](https://quantumcomputingreport.com/about/qcr-alerts-signup-form/), which advertises every week news and job posting from their website
2. [Quantum Computing Institute at ORNL mailing list](https://elist.ornl.gov/mailman/listinfo/qci-external), with news, conferences and job postings in both academia and industry. This one is probably the closer to what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

[Quantiki](https://quantiki.org/) is a great resource for positions and conferences! They don't have their own mailing list (though [they suggest a few](https://quantiki.org/wiki/mailing-lists) including the Oxford Quantum Foundation one) but they have a [calendar of upcoming events](https://%20upcoming%20quantum%20events) and a [job board](https://quantiki.org/jobs) which they keep up-to-date. However I found the most useful thing was to follow them on twitter at @quantiki (and they also have an active [facebook page](https://www.facebook.com/quantiki)).

And I am not associated with Quantiki or anyone at Quantiki, I just think they're great :)